# apt install python3.11 installs multiple versions of python

Tags: apt, docker, python3

I have the below docker file, base image rundeckpro/runner:latest; it has no python installed. After the image is built, there are two versions of python: both python3.10 and python3.11, even though I requested only python3.11. Is there any reason for this, and can I avoid this?

```
ARG RUNNER_VERSION=latest
FROM rundeckpro/runner:${RUNNER_VERSION}

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=python3.11
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gpg-agent && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $PYTHON_VERSION && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $PYTHON_VERSION-venv && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.11 1    

USER runner
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`rundeckpro/runner` is currently based on Ubuntu 22.04, and the default version of Python in 22.04 is 3.10. `software-properties-common` depends on Python, so installing that ends up installing `python3.10`.

Since you only need `software-properties-common` to install [the deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), you can remove it after installing the PPA:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common gpg-agent && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt-get purge -y --autoremove software-properties-common gpg-agent && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $PYTHON_VERSION && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

This will give you `python3.11` but not `python3.10`.

Unfortunately `python3.11-venv`, even in the deadsnakes PPA, depends on `python3-distutils`, which pulls in `python3` and thus `python3.10`.

Also, don’t bother with alternatives, the Python packages don’t use them; if you want `python3`, link it:

```
ln -sf python3.11 /usr/bin/python3
```

(but note that if the `python3` package is installed, this is liable to break things — if a package requires the `python3` package, you should leave the symlink alone, and use `python3.11` explicitly).

Comment: You are right about software-properties-common dependency on python3.10. It did not resolve d my issue, when i tried running each step individually apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3.11 python3.11-venv installs the python3.10 python3.10-minimal python3.11-minimal

Comment: Ah yes, apologies, I’d noted that `python3.10` wasn’t installed after installing `python3.11`, but `python3.11-venv` pulls it in.